# JavaScript: Uncaught TypeError: jQuery.toJSON is not a function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

I have a Tournament Bracket that I found and would like to import it into our vBulletin software.

The script works outside of vBulletin, but when I import it I receive the above error.

```
function saveFn(data, userData) {
  var json = jQuery.toJSON(data);

  $.post("?tid="+ retParam("tid") +"&secretMode="+retParam("secretMode"), {'data':json});                                    
}
```

It's been driving me crazy, I believe that vBulletin is in strict mode but I can't seem to find the problem.

Working: http://doghousesocial.com/area51/brackets.php?tid=1&secretMode=inlanadminmode

Answer (score 1):

You should use the native JSON functions that are available in almost all modern browsers (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON)

Switch to this, it will eliminate the error:

```
var json = JSON.stringify(data);
```

I'm not sure why `jQuery.toJSON(data)` would work outside as $.toJSON is not a function of jQuery. That is why the error came up.

Comment: Just to add on, `JSON` is a global object baked right into ES5 in most implementations. I would prefer `JSON` to any third-party library method simply because it _just works_.

Also, for your information and because you _will_ use it at some point, you can also make use of `JSON.parse('jsonString')` to serialize a JSON object you get over the wire into a regular JS object. This is really useful in many use cases, especially if you are not using a framework that already does this for you automatically.